# Understanding Super() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
```

Hello all I am trying to understand objects and classes. Using `tkinter` the author has created a class which inherits from the `Tk()` class of `tkinter` and proceeds to write his own `__init__` method which I assume overrides the parent class' `__init__`. The author then initialises the parents original `tk.Tk.__init__` method.

Could the author just have used the `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` to achieve the same result?

Comment: Yes, the author could have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe the author could have used `super()` .

The main advantage of super comes with multiple inheritance, [this](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236275) may interest you

Comment: To be clear, you can only do that with python 3.x. With python 2.x, the tkinter classes are old style classes.